# Need to sort strings by part of the string

Tags: java

Say I have an array of strings:

```
String[] array = {
   "2183417234 somerandomtexthere",
   "1234123656 somemorerandomtexthere",
   "1093241066 andevenmore",
   "1243981234 you get what i mean",
   //etc

};
```

How would I sort this array using the long (it's a long) at the start of the string, so it'll end up looking like this:

```
String[] array = {
   "1093241066 andevenmore",
   "1234123656 somemorerandomtexthere",
   "1243981234 you get what i mean",
   "2183417234 somerandomtexthere",
   //etc

};
```

I've tried everyting from making it an arraylist and using Collections#sort to creating my own comparator, to using a sorted map / tree map and I just can't figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your comparator, so we can fix it

Comment: You should definitely use a custom comparator.

Comment: Inside comparator may be split the string and just compare long values

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
static long comparedValue(String s) {
  return Long.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')));
}
```

and then define a Comparator in terms of it:

```
public int compare(String left, String right) {
  return comparedValue(left) - comparedValue(right);
}
```

Comment: This won't work without a cast in there somewhere. Also, comparing by subtracting `long` values can give the wrong result in case of overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> unsorted = Arrays.asList(array);

Function<String, Long> longFunction = new Function<String, Long>() {
  @Override public Long apply(String input) {
    return Long.valueOf(input.split(" ")[0]);
  }
};

List<String> sorted = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(longFunction).immutableSortedCopy(unsorted);
```

Or if you don't wanna use a List (you should always prefer collections to arrays):

```
Arrays.sort(array, Ordering.natural().onResultOf(longFunction));
```

Answer (score 0):

The input that you have shown works perfectly fine. But that's because all of them have the same number of digits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = { "2183417234 somerandomtexthere",
            "1234123656 somemorerandomtexthere", "1093241066 andevenmore",
            "1243981234 you get what i mean", "999 little shorter"
    // etc

    };

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Problems start to occur, when you use some shorter numbers - as 999 shown above...

output will be:

`[1093241066 andevenmore, 1234123656 somemorerandomtexthere, 1243981234 you get what i mean, 2183417234 somerandomtexthere, 999 little shorter]`

So, to make it working allways - you need your custom comparator, that will be able to split given Strings, and then take the number part out of them, and compare them. Using @Marko Topolik solution:

```
static long comparedValue(String s) {
    return Long.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')));
}

public int compare(String left, String right) {

    long result = comparedValue(left) - comparedValue(right);

    boolean numberPartAreEqual = result == 0;
    if (numberPartAreEqual) {
        result = left.compareTo(right);
    }

    return (int) result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom comparator should work fine:

```
public class LongPrefixComparator implements Comparator<String> {
     @Override
     public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         final long pref1 = getPrefixValue(s1);
         final long pref2 = getPrefixValue(s2);
         return s1 == s2 ? 0 : s1 < s2 ? -1 : 1;
     }

     private static long getPrefixValue(String stg) {
         int len = stg.indexOf(' ');
         if (len > 0) {
             try {
                 return Long.parseLong(stg.substring(0, len));
             catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
         }
         return 0L;
     }
}
```